# Zend Framework Logger : Zend DB Logger

Tags: zend-framework, logging

I am using Zend logger as following :-

```
$columnMapping = array('message' => 'message', 'created_at' => 'timestamp');
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Db($dbAdapater, 'log', $columnMapping);
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
$logger->info('Sample log data');
```

Now if I want to bind more fields which are not defined as default (as we can see in **$columnMapping** array), e.g. user_name, user_type etc, then what should I do?

To be simple I want to achieve following:-

```
$columnMapping = array('user_defined_field1' => 'user_defined_val_1');
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Db($dbAdapater, 'log', $columnMapping);
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
$logger->info('Sample log data');
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logger definition:

```
$columnMapping = array(
    'message' => 'message',
    'user_defined_field1' => 'user_defined_field1');
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Db($dbAdapater, 'log', $columnMapping);
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
```

When 'user_defined_val1' data is available, call setEventItem() function:

```
$logger->setEventItem('user_defined_field1', 'user_defined_val1');
$logger->info('Sample log data');
```

More detail:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.overview.html - Understanding Log events